# EPPlus: Value not extracted after calling calculate function

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am working with VS2013 and winform template. i am generating excel with EPPlus. i need to check if cell value is less than 0 then will set color.

i have few cells where formula has been set. when i open excel file after generation then right value is showing in cell after from formula but when i am trying to programmatically read cell value which has formula then getting empty value.

My formula looks like **IF(E4="","",IF(B4=0,"",IF(E4=0,"",IF(B4="","",IF(B4<0,-(E4/B4-1),(E4/B4-1))))))**

Formula i set without **=** sign

```
if (ws.Cells[DeltaPercentagePeriod].Formula != "")
 {
      ws.Cells[DeltaPercentagePeriod].Calculate();
      ws.Cells[DeltaPercentagePeriod].Value  //getting empty value                 
    
 }
```

Anyone please tell me where i made the mistake for which i am not getting value from formula. Thanks

Comment: There appears to some bug with versions after 4.5.3.1. I have the version 4.5.3.3. Once I downgraded to 4.5.3.1, it works.  Although, I really want version 5.5.5 to work but the calculated value is keep coming back as null.

Comment: i am using version 4.0.6.0